# mv: target 'hadoop/' is not a directory

Tags: fedora, hadoop

I am using Fedora 23 which is installed on Oracle VM. I am at the Downloading Hadoop step of the documentation [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_enviornment_setup.htm). When I run the following command in Fedora, I can see the hadoop user listed:

```
[hadoop@localhost home]$ ls
user  hadoop
```

When I run the following command `mv hadoop-2.6.4/* to hadoop/`, I get the following error :

`mv: target 'hadoop/' is not a directory`

So, do I need to create directory at the following level `[hadoop@localhost local]$`?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jakuje I am trying to run the step ` mv hadoop-2.4.1/* to hadoop/` mentioned in the documentation I am referring to and getting directory related error.

Comment: Is 'hadoop' a file right now? Do `ls -l`

Comment: @JeffSchaller Here is the result of `ls -l` http://i.stack.imgur.com/XTZ7Q.png

Comment: I'm confused.  Your first 'ls' shows a hadoop entry, but the latest one doesn't. If there truly isn't a hadoop directory, then the error makes sense. `mkdir hadoop` would be one way to fix it.

Comment: After reading the linked doc I suspect they just want you to do `mv hadoop-2.6.4 hadoop`

Comment: @JeffSchaller I updated my first `ls`, there was a mistake in writing the command from me. They are just users listed inside the home directory.Could you take a look now? what would `mv hadoop-2.6.4 hadoop` would do as I don't have `hadoop` directory over there?

Comment: Dropping the * in the mv command makes it mean "rename this directory to this other name"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of reading the linked article author's mind, I think that the following instructions are broken in a few ways:

```
$ su 
password: 
# cd /usr/local 
# wget http://apache.claz.org/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.4.1/ 
hadoop-2.4.1.tar.gz 
# tar xzf hadoop-2.4.1.tar.gz 
# mv hadoop-2.4.1/* to hadoop/ 
# exit
```

They start off as functioning commands, but the wget command is broken in two ways -- the filename is broken off the end of the URL, and that specific version/directory does not exist on that server.  For the version that you appearing to be targeting, the correct command would be `wget http://apache.claz.org/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.6.4/hadoop-2.6.4.tar.gz`.

After the tar command, the `mv` command is a mix of English and Unix. If I was to guess, I would say that the author had an existing hadoop directory and was suggesting to move the **contents** of hadoop-2.4.1 into the hadoop directory. If you are starting from scratch, it would be simpler to say `mv hadoop-2.6.4 hadoop` (using your version number).

Putting it all together, with your version number, I would suggest:

```
$ su 
password: 
# cd /usr/local 
# wget http://apache.claz.org/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.6.4/hadoop-2.6.4.tar.gz 
# tar xzf hadoop-2.6.4.tar.gz 
# mv hadoop-2.6.4 hadoop
# exit
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. One more question. While running the command `mv hadoop-2.6.4 hadoop` should first create a director named `hadoop` inside local directory `local` so that the next time I run `ls -l`, I would see it listed here : http://i.stack.imgur.com/XTZ7Q.png

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: So, the `mv` command you suggested is just used to rename the `hadoop-2.6.4` to `hadoop` ?

Comment: Yes. Fifteen characters here.

Comment: Why did you mention "fifteen characters here"?

Comment: Site requires >= 15 characters in a comment, and "yes" was too short and I wasn't creative enough to come up with something else to fill in :)